# generate custom permalink based on a custom field - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm a newbie to the Wordpress.

So far I have a custom post type called 'property'. This post type has one custom field called 'property_city'.

In WP-admin - permalink setting, I have selected Post name option. So, posts of this custom post type have URLs like:

http://xxx.local/properties/edge-apartments/

http://xxx.local/properties/northgate-point/

What I want to have those URL to be generated using the city of the property and also I want to change properties prefix with student-properties like that:

http://xxx.local/student-properties/Manchester/edge-apartments/

http://xxx.local/student-properties/Chester/northgate-point/

I have tried various plugin and various code, but none of them worked as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try Permalink manager plugin it works for me here is the link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

Comment: see this : http://competitionmantra.com/en/category/events-2016/january-2016/international-news-jan-2016/ is this actually you want permalink structure ?